# KeyError after assigning simple variable naming

Tags: python, web-scraping

I haven't used python in a long time and am trying to follow a website to scrape some information off of ESPN's fantasy football website. The wesbite I'm using is https://stmorse.github.io/journal/espn-fantasy-v3.html. When I try the code listed below I get KeyError: 'schedule'.

I tried following the code on the website exactly and it gives the same error. I opened up the api on https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2019/segments/0/leagues/14380834?view=mMatchup and see that there is a place for schedule so not sure what else I need to do.

```
league_id = 14380834
year = 2019
url = "https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2019/segments/0/leagues/14380834/"

r = requests.get(url)
d = r.json()
r = requests.get(url, params={"view": "mMatchup"})

df = [[
        game['matchupPeriodId'],
        game['home']['teamId'], game['home']['totalPoints'],
        game['away']['teamId'], game['away']['totalPoints']
    ] for game in d['schedule']]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Week', 'Team1', 'Score1', 'Team2', 'Score2'])
df['Type'] = ['Regular' if w<=14 else 'Playoff' for w in df['Week']]
df.head()
```

My expected results would be the 5 columns I call for week to score2 populated via the espn site.

The traceback is:

```
File "C:/Users/jacob/PycharmProjects/FF_stuff/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    ] for game in d['schedule']]
KeyError: 'schedule'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: @hilton92, I'm not entirely sure what that means, isn't d just storing the info? When I manually look at the webpage there is schedule info.

Comment: @Chris sounds good, just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the json `d` from the request which contains the param, not the first request.

This works

```
r = requests.get(url, params={"view": "mMatchup"})
d = r.json()

df = [[
        game['matchupPeriodId'],
        game['home']['teamId'], game['home']['totalPoints'],
        game['away']['teamId'], game['away']['totalPoints']
    ] for game in d['schedule']]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Week', 'Team1', 'Score1', 'Team2', 'Score2'])
df['Type'] = ['Regular' if w<=14 else 'Playoff' for w in df['Week']]
df.head()
```

The `KeyError` was coming because the request without the param didnt have `'schedule'` information in there. You can do `d.keys()` to see what keys a `dict` has

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Now just need to figure out why pd. isn't being recognized in the next line lol. Thanks!

Comment: Did you `import pandas as pd`?  - You need to alias the import, `import pandas` will mean that you need to type `pandas.DataFrame`

Also if the answer worked remember to accept it

Comment: Yep it just needed to wait 5 minutes before I could accept.